# How can I use JSTL in the following jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have made a jsp page and used the following statement in that:

```
<% if(cm.getSessionData("User")!=null && cm.getSessionData("User").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("U")) { %>
```

where cm is the object of CacheManager.

I just want to know if this jsp statement can be made better using JSTL. If yes, how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty cm.sessionData and fn:toLowerCase(cm.sessionData)=='u'}">
...
</c:if>
```